# Google Tag Manager in React SPA application with react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, google-tag-manager

The issue is Google Tag Manager duplicates when I go through app by Link (react-router).

The Google Tag Assistant show me that.

[image: GoogleTagAssistant]

I have included GTM script in head section of index.html

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
      new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
  })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-KCVFSLC');
</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

May be somebody face to that problem?

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue of Tag Assistant Plugin.

Plugin shows new data about trackers and doesn't remove previous data when object history has been changed.

Also I checked all changed data after manipulation with history and I can't find everywhere duplicated trackers.

And then I found this discussion with the same problem: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/9l4ENQN3HsE

Which confirms my guesses.